# Can I use a sander or grinder to polish quartz countertop edges?

Tags: kitchen-counters, quartz

I had a quartz countertop installed, however they did a poor job where it was cut. They used max 200 grit sandpaper with an angle grinder.  Also they applied a sealer and now it has some kind of stains.

I have an orbital sander tool and angle grinder. Can I use these like they do in order to fix it? Probably with higher grit gradually.

Do I need special sandpaper like diamond?

[image]

Comment: Sanding any stone without water will cover everything in nasty, abrasive dust that will dutifully eat into hinges, drawer mechanisms, etc., shortening their lives. Whatever you do, use wet stone tooling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only used tools designed specifically for this purpose. For example, Makita makes a stone polishing tool. It looks like an angle grinder, but it has different attachments, variable speed control, and a built in water supply. I am not sure if you can dry sand the quartz, I would imagine it would be extremely dusty. If you're going to wet-sand, you'd have to find a way to protect the surrounding area from water spray.
I think a significant difference between a regular angle grinder and a polisher is the speed. The tool I mentioned earlier can vary speed between 2000 and 4000 rpm, while single speed angle grinders run at a constant, typically higher RPM in the 5000-10000 range. If your angle grinder has variable speed, it might be OK.

And yes, you would want to use stone polishing disks instead of regular sand paper. You would probably wear through the sand paper rather quickly. You can easily find kits of these online for less then $50. They would include all the steps you need (50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1500, 3000 for example). If you're just doing these edges, you will barely use the pads and can maybe even sell them to someone looking to do a similar project when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a recent install, have them come back and fix it. They should be willing to stand behind their work.

If you do it yourself, you *will* grind/sand/polish through any sealer that may be left, so be prepared to reseal the top or you're guaranteed to end up with more staining. If you need more details on *how* to seal it, that's material for a whole new question.

Comment: The top stains but it comes ready from the factory since it is quartz engineered stone. The edges were polished with an angular grinder with 200grit max. I told them about this when they were installing it and they told me that this is how the stone looks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.